# Login & Registration Tab missing in Build Your Own( LWR)

Tags: lightning-community, partner-communities, partner-portal, experience-builder-page, lwr

I am not getting **Login & Registration** Tab on the Administration setup page. As per portal documentation, it should be there.

My community is already activated and published as well. I have opted for Authenticated portal as well which is required for that. Attached is an image for the Administration page.

Am I missing something? or any kind of license issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This was a license issue and it is resolved now.

We got a **Courtesy Partner license** from Salesforce to do some POC for the partner community. This **Login & Registration** Tab was not showing due it this.  When that **Courtesy license** expired and we added our actual license it started showing.

[image]